# How to convert DER or PEM format of ECC Public Key to RAW Format

Tags: security, openssl, pem, der, ecdh

In OpenSSL or WolfSSL

I know there is always a way to convert RAW public key format into DER or PEM using OpenSSL or WolfSSL but how to convert DER or PEM public key format back to RAW key format.

The DER format is (in hex 158 bytes in length)

```
30 81 9b 30 10 06 07 2a 86 48 ce 3d 02 01 06 05 2b 81 04 00 23 03 81 86 
00 04 00 e8 ff 35 e0 32 6e 57 9b 43 f9 05 97 d0 e1 e5 df 1e 63 51 ed 30 
e3 11 22 c3 47 bf 8b a0 1d f0 bc 0a 74 38 ea ee 47 4e 0e 9e ba 87 ad 17 
2a 2c ee 25 81 40 54 63 93 63 a0 38 1c cd b7 5b e7 8b a7 b5 00 ea 60 94 
44 aa 85 ee e8 af 15 e2 d8 0d 1a 07 8a 3d 9e 9f 97 17 53 d9 58 26 b9 a9 
0a 33 92 d9 93 3b 39 a5 d6 cb 87 88 97 59 71 88 e0 81 db 31 4e 73 80 1d 
8b c8 13 bc 34 54 71 01 1b b0 be ed 22 a6
```

Comment: Does this "RAW key format" start with a byte valued `02`, `03` or `04` in hex?

Comment: no it's not I think it will be in a compressed version

Comment: Compressed *points* would start with `02`, `03`. "RAW format" has little meaning by itself. It would be nice if you could provide an example and / or point out the format specification within OpenSSL.

Comment: sorry my mistake, it's uncompressed version. I only have the der format of the key I will add the der format in the post

Comment: That's indeed a [DER encoded SubjectPublicKey](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQA6P814DJuV5tD-QWX0OHl3x5jUe0w4xEiw0e_i6Ad8LwKdDjq7kdODp66h60XKizuJYFAVGOTY6A4HM23W-eLp7UA6mCURKqF7uivFeLYDRoHij2en5cXU9lYJrmpCjOS2ZM7OaXWy4eIl1lxiOCB2zFOc4Adi8gTvDRUcQEbsL7tIqY) (with an uncompressed key hidden inside the BIT STRING). Now the question remains: what should the raw key look like?

Comment: really helpful decoder link, but I guess your question is my question for this post, how to get the RAW key format from here

Comment: I believe the raw key format should be the public key string portion of this DER format, and x and y take an equal amount of bytes

Comment: Well, normally you would have to parse the structure, but you can cheat and get the 2 * roundup(521 / 8) = 132 bytes from the tail of the structure, with X and Y both being encoded as 66 unsigned  bytes - big endian - in this case). Or use 133 bytes if you need to include the `04` uncompressed point indicator as well. Of course, that little trick will fail if somebody supplies a compressed point, as those are 66 bytes smaller (just the X coordinate and a single bit indicating how to calculate the Y coordinate). Other trickery can be used to get around that.